# How to map reparted sequence in VIM?

Tags: vim

I want to map 'space+u' as 'Ctrl+u', I have this at my config:

```
nnoremap <space>u <C-u>
```

But it isn't work as Ctrl+u. When I press 'space+u', firstly it works fine, but when I press 'u' second time - it works an 'undo' (I'm holding 'space' since first time). I want to make it works as , when I press 'Ctrl', hold it and can hit 'u' any times I want.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The mapping you made means "space first, then u in succession". Not simultaneous action there, which explains the behavior for subsequent calls.
Vim listens to key press events; the system reports it that this-and-that key was typed, with that-and-that modifier (ctrl, super). *Few* applications would understand to check arbitrary combinations of keys being held (outside of games).

For this sort of hacks there is an established project for Linux systems called https://github.com/alols/xcape. In combination of xcape and xmodmap you can basically map `<space>` as a modifier key like less used Hyper key (this is the part for xmodmap). Then you would use xcape to make sure that pressing space in isolation would result in a space character. People have used xcape to map `return` as a right Ctrl key (while Caps Lock would act as the left Ctrl).

Comment: WTF? Why VIM is listening only key press events? We have actually KEY_DOWN, KEY_UP and KEY_PRESS (KEY_DOWN + KEY_UP) events. We will not need to map <space> as a modifier key if VIM supports full keyboard events. It's very bad. I don't know what to do - I want to create portable vimrc file.

Comment: @Promix17: well it is kind of limiting but I know of very few apps that supported held keys separately.